# cannot able to execute jar file on windows

Tags: java, jar

PS D:\my_proj_2023\springboot-microservice\department-service\target> java -jar -Dserver.port=8082 department-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
Error: Unable to access jarfile .port=8082

i checked the path it is correct,but getting same thing

Comment: Put the `-D` param before `-jar` The latter has to go immediately before the jar file name

Comment: In my opinion it's not too hard to look at the error message and figure out what's wrong. Have you done that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument after the -jar argument is treated as the file to execute, so it is parsing **-Dserver.port=8082** as the file name. This means you need to use the command **java -Dserver.port=8082 -jar department-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar**.